# Win 10: USB 3 device connected to USB3 port but still get "This device can perform faster when connected to USB 3"

Tags: windows-10, usb

I've a network card (RTL8812BU) which has an USB 3 interface and it's connected to an USB3 port, still I get the warning about:

"This device can perform faster when connected to USB 3" in the "Bluetooth and other devices".

I can confirm that it's connected to an USB 3 port even by the fact that the USB Viewer shows it's directly connected to the USB 3.0 HUB (Asus Z97-K mainboard). This happens systematically on any of the 6 (4 rear + 2 front) USB3 ports.

I want to troubleshoot this but I don't understand where I could get any logs telling me why I'm getting this error.

**My question is**: where do I find logs explaining exactly what went wrong/why is this warning happening? Any windows registry, event viewer, log files etc... where to look for?

Comment: Try to Update your USB drivers

Comment: Already did and they are the latest: however here the question is about where to find error/log diagnostics to tell me why this is happening!

Comment: Interference between 2.4 GHz radio and 2.5 GHz USB3.0 fundamental frequency is a fairly common thing. I am afraid there is no solution for this particular product.

Comment: thanks @Ale..chenski but this is not the case: the card has been forced to link only at 5Ghz frequence, so the 2.4 is not being used

Comment: You can't avoid emissions in 2.5GHz range by forcing something or not forcing. You are getting this error because the USB link failed its built-in bitrate quality test and dropped to USB2 mode. But if you want to find out "what exactly went wrong" you need to deploy Win10 trace log tools, google for [how to capture event trace log (ETL)]. Good luck. And the answer will still be, the port status gets downgraded into HS mode. That's all the system can know.

Comment: thanks @Ale..chenski for the detailed explanation: I will check the logs and get back. I've also a different WIFi card (RTL8814AU) that does not show this issue and might try to compare the logs!